# dex2jar and JD-GUI label statements

Tags: java, android, jar, dex2jar

I used dex2jar  to get jar from an apk and to view it used JD-GUI .

But I notice there are label symbols such as following,

```
      if (this.data.length != 7)
              break label279;

    // more code here
     label279: short[] aos = { 0, 0 };
```

is it something added by compiler(or Obfuscate) ? is there any other tool that could use to avoid these labels?

---

If found this
https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/source/browse/dex-ir/src/main/java/com/googlecode/dex2jar/ir/ts/CleanLabel.java?r=e8b872fdfce8a5a39aa7df083c46ec724fa8d3f4

is it something relate for this cleaning ?

Answer (score 0):

Further research:

```
if (Math.abs(k) > this.mMaxRotationAngle)
  if (k >= 0)
    break label100;
label100: for (k = -this.mMaxRotationAngle; ; k = this.mMaxRotationAngle)
{
  transformImageBitmap((ImageView)paramView, paramTransformation, k);
  break;
}
```

From the above code by natural observation I changed the code to :

```
if (Math.abs(k) > this.mMaxRotationAngle)

// label100: 
for (k = -this.mMaxRotationAngle; ; k = this.mMaxRotationAngle)
{
  if (k >= 0)
    break;// label100;
  transformImageBitmap((ImageView)paramView, paramTransformation, k);
 // break;
}
```

Still the `label100` remains as a mystery... Wondering how does dex2jar handles the situations when it is unaware of the code.

the existence of `:` operator also suggests that there might be a `for each` loop

If at some point in future this mystery is resolved then please notify me too.

thanks.

Comment: I too am curious about this. In the code I'm looking at, I'm seeing `break label200;` when the code is not in label 200 and label 200 is inside of a for loop defined as `for(;;)` I'm not sure if this is caused by obfuscation or what the issue is. All I know is that clearly breaking out of a label you're not in and into a label inside of a for loop is certainly will not compile. So there's no way this was meaning of the byte code.